# Find the variance of the sample mean

Tags: statistics, covariance, variance

Hi I'm trying to find the variance of the sample mean below. I'm confused about the 4th and 5th lines, particularly where does the j' come from and why has it been introduced? Thanks any help appreciated.

$\overline{x}=\frac{1}{3n}\sum_{i=1}^{3}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{ij}$

$var(\overline{x})=var(\frac{1}{3n}\sum_{i=1}^{3}\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{ij})$

$=\frac{1}{9n^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{3}var(\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_{ij})$

$=\frac{1}{3n^{2}}E[\sum_{j=1}^{n}(X_{ij}-\mu )]^{2}$

$=\frac{1}{3n^{2}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{j'=1}^{n}E[(X_{ij}-\mu)(X_{ij'}-\mu)]$

$=\frac{1}{3n^{2}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}E[(X_{ij}-\mu)^{2}]+2\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{j'=j+1}^{n}E[(X_{ij}-\mu)(X_{ij'}-\mu)]$

Comment: What happens when you square a sum? You have to multiply out each pair of summands. That line achieves exactly that.

Comment: @Ian shouldn't it be $(X_{ij}-\mu)(X_{ij}-\mu)$ then?

Comment: No, because you need *each* pair of summands, including those with different values of $j$. For example $(x_1+x_2)^2=x_1^2+x_1 x_2 + x_2 x_1 + x_2^2$.

Comment: @Ian thanks for that. Can you explain why they used j' = j + 1? is it just to make j' != j?

Comment: The point is really to separate out the first term, where you're multiplying the summands with the same value of $j$. What's left over happens to be that other term. You could write it as $\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{j'=1,j' \neq j}^n$ just as well, of course.

Comment: @Ian ah I see. And the step from the fourth line to the fifth line, is it similar to the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235243/taking-the-square-of-a-finite-series

I just don't see where the 2 comes from

Comment: You can split the sum I wrote between terms with $j'<j$ and $j'>j$, and because of commutativity properties the two are the same, so they just write it as twice the sum with $j'>j$.